# Pattern Match "Empty" Term in NonCommutativeMultiply

Tags: pattern-matching, design-patterns

Not sure if this has been asked before, please point me to the post if it has.

Is there a way to treat terms like `(b+c)`, `a**(b+c)`, `(b+c)**d` and `a**(b+c)**d` together? By that I mean, is there a pattern like `a_(Something or nothing)**(b_+c_)**d_(Something or nothing)` and which allows for distributivity to be defined as something like

```
NCExpand[a_(Something or nothing)**(b_+c_)**d_(Something or nothing)]:= a**b**d+a**c**d
```

where for the case where `a` or `d` is not present they are not present in the expanded version.

**Edit**

Based on what is said in the comments I've done
[image]

But as can be seen from the output it doesn't work when the head is not `NonCommutativeMultiply`. I would like to be able to include it in the same definition.

Comment: Yes, see [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankNullSequence.html). Example: `f[a___,b_+c_,d___]:=f[a,b,d]+f[a,c,d]`. For a tutorial, see [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Patterns.html#17118).

Comment: Could you explain how you would specifically implement it for the example I gave?

Comment: I guess what I mean is if I apply what you gave to my example for `NCExpand[b+c]` it will just return `NCExpand[b+c]`. I was wondering if you could somehow include this case in the definition of `NCExpand[]` without requiring a separate definition `NCExpand[b_+c_]:=NCExpand[b]+NCExpand[c]`.

Comment: That case is included, if you use 3 underscores for a and d.

Comment: How is it included?

Comment: file:///home/jacovantonder/%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F/%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%83%E3%83%88/Screenshot%20from%202022-10-29%2011-32-13.png

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood your comment. I have no useful answer in that case. 
Maybe use a different kind of definition altogether, such as `NCExpand[expr_] := expr //. NonCommutativeMultiply[a___,b_+c_,d___] :> a**b**d+a**c**d`. Maybe look at the NCAlgebra package for inspiration, for example [the definition of `ExpandNonCommutativeMultiply`](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC/blob/54b2a81ebda9e5260328f88f83f56fe8cf472ac3/NCAlgebra/NonCommutativeMultiply.m#L219). Generally, I like multiple definitions, because it often gives readable code, but I understand that that is not your question.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: You might want to consider simply using `NCExpand[a_] := Distribute[a, Plus, NonCommutativeMultiply]`. That said, the following provides a useful way of making `NonCommutativeMultiply` behave like `Times` with an identity (which is beneficial even outside of this problem), and also answers the original question.

So, if you want to mirror how e.g. `Times` works, then what you want to do is exploit the `OneIdentity` attribute (which `NonCommutativeMultiply` already has), `Default` values and `Optional` patterns, and implement an identity value for `NonCommutativeMultiply`.

---

If `f` has the attribute `OneIdentity`, that means that `f[x]`, `f[f[x]]`, etc. will match `x`.

`Optional` patterns match a pattern to a provided default value if the expression does not appear. But there are two ways to provide a default value: either inline or via a value that's globally associated with the enclosing head. For example, if we have `f[a_:0, b_] := {a,b}`, then `f[2]` will be `{0,2}` thanks to the inline `Optional` pattern `a_:0`. But we could also use `f[a_., b_]` (`a_.` is `Optional[a]`) together with a separate evaluation of `Default[f] = 0` to get the same result.

This works for pattern matching too: e.g. `Default[Times]` is `1`, and `f[Times[x_.,3]] := x` means that `f[3 y]` gives `y`, while `f[3]` gives `1`. The `OneIdentity` attribute means that `3` matches `Times[3]` which matches `Times[x_.,3]`.

To be honest, I'm not 100% sure why `b+c` doesn't then match `NonCommutativeMultiply[a___,b_+c_,d___]`. It seems `OneIdentity` only meshes well with `Optional` patterns. However, it *does* match `NonCommutativeMultiply[a_., b + c, d_.]`.

Here's a gotcha to watch out for: the `Default` value must be set *before* any definitions involving default patterns are evaluated. I suspect `Optional` is partially magical.

#### Making `NonCommutativeMultiply` behave well

We then also need to actually make our `Default` value actually behave like an identity for `NonCommutativeMultiply`. To do this, we add a definition using the intercept trick.

We *also* need to make `NonCommutativeMultiply[a]` be `a` and `NonCommutativeMultiply[]` be the default value. Due to, I suspect (but possibly not), the magic of `Optional`, we need to temporarily clear `NonCommutativeMultiply`'s attributes while setting that definition.

---

So, putting it all together:

```
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];

Default[NonCommutativeMultiply] = 1; (* or whatever value you'd like here *)

(* Set unary and nullary behavior: *)
Block[{a = Attributes[NonCommutativeMultiply]},
  Attributes[NonCommutativeMultiply] = {};
  NonCommutativeMultiply[a_.] := a;
  Attributes[NonCommutativeMultiply] = a;
  ];

(* Make Default[NonCommutativeMultiply] behave as an identity
   for NonCommutativeMultiply and avoid infinite recursion
   via the intercept trick: *)
NCMIntercept = True;

NonCommutativeMultiply[a_, b__] :=
 Block[{NCMIntercept = False},
  NonCommutativeMultiply @@ DeleteCases[{a,b}, Default[NonCommutativeMultiply]]
 ] /; NCMIntercept

Protect[NonCommutativeMultiply, NCMIntercept];

NCExpand[a_. ** (b_ + c_) ** d_.] := a ** b ** d + a ** c ** d
```

(Note that while `NCExpand[b + c]` works as expected, `NCExpand[b]` is still undefined! Another definition (`NCExpand[a_] := a`) is needed.)

It is possible to do this a bit differently if you want `NonCommutativeMultiply[a]` to not evaluate further (the default behavior), perhaps by using `Default[NonCommutativeMultiply] := Sequence[]`. I haven't explored this though.

Hope this helps! :)